# Stripe Connect Charges

Tags: stripe-payments

We have a UK Stripe account that our customers connect their Stripe standalone accounts to.  These connected accounts are in different countries and their associated customers make payments in our customers own currency. For example, our UK customers will have UK Stripe Bank accounts and their customers will make payments in pounds(£). Our Singapore customers all have Singapore bank accounts and their customers will make payments in Singapore dollars.  When a Singapore end customer purchases something from our Singapore customer then we will make a charge on their behalf using our Private key and their Connected account ID. Our Stripe account never receives any monies from this process.

Are there any international restrictions with doing this and are there any currency transfer charges due to our platform account not being in the same country as our customer accounts?

Comment: Use Bitcoin. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are currency conversion charges for stripe when your customer pays in currency other than currency you are accepting in your account.

please refer this [link](https://stripe.com/docs/currencies/conversions) to know more about the currency conversion charges for stripe